# Applying animation when leaving hover state

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have some animations I found online. I am able to apply them when I hover the div i've assigned the class to but I can't figure out how to animate when I leave hover.

What I am hoping to get is a control bar which slides up when i hover and slides down when i leave.

HTML:

```
<div id="controls" class="cAnimated fadeInUp fadeInDown">
        <div id="defaultBar">
               <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
   <button id="playButton"><img src="images/icons/play.png" /></button>
   <button id="vol" onclick="showSlider()"><img src="images/icons/vol.png" /></button>      
   <button id="containSlider"> 
   <input type="range" id="vSlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/></button>
    <div id='containTime'><span id='timeDisplay'>0:00</span><span>/</span><span id='durationDisplay'>0:00</span></div>
   <button id="full"><img src="images/icons/full.png" /></button>
   <button id="mute"><img src="images/icons/mute.png" /></button>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated:hover {
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.9s;
    animation-duration: 0.9s;
}
.animated.hinge {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
@keyframes fadeInUp {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.fadeInUp:hover {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
@keyframes fadeInDown {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(-20px);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
}

.fadeInDown  {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

More code: http://jsfiddle.net/EaC82/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much cleaner with CSS transitions:

```
 .fadeInUp {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    -moz-transition:    all 300ms ease;
    -o-transition:      all 300ms ease;
    -ms-transition:     all 300ms ease;
    transition:         all 300ms ease;
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0,10px);
    -moz-transform:     translate(0,10px);
    -o-transform:       translate(0,10px);
    -ms-transform:      translate(0,10px);
    transform:          translate(0,10px);
    opacity: 0;

}

.fadeInUp:hover {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0,0);
    -moz-transform:     translate(0,0);
    -o-transform:       translate(0,0);
    -ms-transform:      translate(0,0);
    transform:          translate(0,0);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k3Y5x/